# Using git Repo https://github.com/tylerjroach/eventsource-android and it is not working?

Tags: java, android, git, sockets, jboss

I am using this android git REPO https://github.com/tylerjroach/eventsource-android
I implemented the method

```
public void onConnects() {

    Thread eventThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                eventSource = new EventSource(URI.create(myApiUrl), new SSEHandler(), true);
                eventSource.connect();
            } catch(Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    eventThread.start();

}
```

But I had to change eventsource.connect(); from private to public to allow this to work. I then, put in my Api Url and the parameters and it failed. What is going on here??

Here is My Stack Trace

> 02-18 02:16:37.315 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to open a socket.
>   02-18 02:16:37.315 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketChannel.newSocket(NioClientSocketChannel.java:49)
>   02-18 02:16:37.315 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketChannel.(NioClientSocketChannel.java:83)
>   02-18 02:16:37.315 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketChannelFactory.newChannel(NioClientSocketChannelFactory.java:167)
>   02-18 02:16:37.315 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketChannelFactory.newChannel(NioClientSocketChannelFactory.java:86)
>   02-18 02:16:37.315 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:218)
>   02-18 02:16:37.315 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:188)
>   02-18 02:16:37.315 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:159)
>   02-18 02:16:37.315 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err:     at tylerjroach.com.eventsource_android.EventSource.connect(EventSource.java:149)
>   02-18 02:16:37.315 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.athena.myapplication.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:63)
>   02-18 02:16:37.315 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>   02-18 02:16:37.315 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
>   02-18 02:16:37.315 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:576)
>   02-18 02:16:37.315 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.nio.SocketChannelImpl.(SocketChannelImpl.java:102)
>   02-18 02:16:37.315 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.nio.SocketChannelImpl.(SocketChannelImpl.java:93)
>   02-18 02:16:37.315 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.nio.SelectorProviderImpl.openSocketChannel(SelectorProviderImpl.java:49)
>   02-18 02:16:37.315 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:81)
>   02-18 02:16:37.315 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketChannel.newSocket(NioClientSocketChannel.java:47)
>   02-18 02:16:37.315 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err:   ... 9 more
>   02-18 02:16:37.315 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
>   02-18 02:16:37.325 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
>   02-18 02:16:37.325 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:181)
>   02-18 02:16:37.325 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:561)
>   02-18 02:16:37.325 18398-18411/com.athena.myapplication W/System.err:   ... 14 more

Comment: I know this is a little late, but this is my project. I hate to ask this, but did you add internet permissions in the manifest?